# selenium cant find element - no such element

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have this website where I want to get the element post-title.

[image]

I tried `driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-1di2uql-1 vYcWR")` but that just returns: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".sc-1di2uql-1 vYcWR"}

I have seen similar posts where the problem was that the searched element was in an iframe but I cant see anything like that here. Then again I started to learn about webscraping about a week ago so theres probably a lot I dont know.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: is that the source code, or what you get when using browser developer tools (the live HTML code)?

Comment: yes, that is from the browser dev tools

Comment: The element you're looking for has two classes separated by a space. Search for one of the classes.

Comment: thats's 2 classes? wouldnt have ever found that out on myself. but that alone doesnt solve it. While searching for a way to copy all that code from the screenshot I found out that all the copy options for that element start  with "#renderPageContentWrapper". That one contains "role = main" so I guess I have to treat that as an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with selenium before. My problem was that the website would rotate class names, so every time you access the page they would be different. Judging by the way the class names are on your website I think you have the same issue. If this is the case, you are just trying to look for something that is not there. What I did to solve this problem was using `driver.get_element_by_xpath(“PASTE FULL XPATH OF THE ELEMENT”)` instead of finding the element using its css class.

To get the full path of an element: in the developer tools, right click on the element and click copy FULL XPATH.